# SQL server: find last three years customer details

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table accountmaster.
 when given a date,it should return number  of customers enrolled(DOE) in last three years of the given date.

here is my query, which is not returning any values.plz help me with changes .TIA

```
select count(ACID) as  numberofcustomers from ACCOUNTMASTER
where 
 datepart(yy,doe)>= datepart(yy,dateadd(yy,-2,'2012/04/10'))
 and
 doe<= datepart(yy,'2012/04/10')
```

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: If that is real data you should remove it immediately.

Comment: Its not a real one.anyways I deleted that.Thanx for the info.:)

Comment: The issue is `doe<= datepart(yy,'2012/04/10')`. doe is a date (or datetime) and datepart returns an integer. Therefore doe is being converted to an integer (which will be the number of days since 1900-01-01 (e.g. today is 42815). So any date past the 3rd of March, 1905 will necessarily be greater than the datepart(year) of that date. What you actually want is something like `where doe >= dateadd(year, -3, givendate) and doe <= givendate` or something like that.

Comment: select count(ACID) as  numberofcustomers from ACCOUNTMASTER
where doe>= dateadd(yy,-2,'2012/04/10') and doe<= '2012/04/10'          .This query is only displaying the results between 2010-04-10and 2010-04-10. But I want results from the whole years 2010,2011,2012.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is an apparent misunderstanding on what `DATEPART` does, and how to compare dates. So let us break down your `WHERE` clause.

```
where 
    datepart(yy,doe)>= datepart(yy,dateadd(yy,-2,'2012/04/10'))
```

This clause compares the year value of the date in column doe with the year of a date two years prior to a fixed date, representing the date submitted by the user.  So, `datepart(yy, dateadd(yy, -2,'2012/04/10'))` returns a value of 2010 as an `int`. This is compared with the `datepart(yy,doe)`, which returns the integer year of the date value stored in the `doe` column. Since these two data types are both `int,` the compare does what it should and returns information from records dated 2010/01/01 and later. No problems here - unless you are expecting to return data from 2010/**04/10** forward, in which case you want to compare the value `dateadd(yy, -2,'2012/04/10')` to the value in the `doe` column.

```
and doe<= datepart(yy,'2012/04/10')
```

In this case, there is a comparison issue. You are attempting to compare the integer value 2012 with the date value in the `doe` column. Since these are not the same data type, we need to find out what is being compared.

I assume that the `doe` column is a datetime data type (if it was a date or datetime2, you would be getting an error.) An integer can be compared to a datetime, since SQL Server uses a numeric datatype to represent the datetime data type. A value of 2012 represents the date 1905/07/06 (use `CAST(2012 as datetime)` to see for yourself), so the WHERE clause translates out to something like:

```
WHERE datepart(year, doe) >= 2010 
    AND doe < '1905/07/06'
```

Since a date can not be both before July, 1905 and on or after Jan, 2010, no data is returned.

What is actually needed here depends on whether or not you only want to compare years, or you want to compare year/month/day. For years only, you can replace the last `doe` with `DATEPART(year, doe)` and have a functional query, albeit not a fast one. To compare year/month/day, use the `DATEADD` as mentioned above, and just use the actual entered date in the final comparison.

Hopefully, that helps.

Comment: Thx for correcting . I missed Datepart after AND. Its working now.Thq:)